# Return values for string matching

Tags: regex, perl, awk, pattern-matching

Pretend I have a code in awk:

```
str_1 = "abc123defg";
match(str_1, /[0-9]+/);
num_1 = substr(str_1, RSTART, RLENGTH);
```

Then num_1 will be "123". What is the Perl version of the same task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd translate that to:

```
my $num_1 = ($str_1 =~ /(\d+)/)[0];
```

Comment: Thank you! So if I extend this string to "abc123def456ghi789jkl" then [0] = 123; [1] = 456 etc... Is that correct?

Comment: I think you would need to add the `/g` modifier to make that work.

Answer (score 3):

I would usually do something like

```
my ($num_1) = $str_1 =~ /(\d+)/;
```

or

```
my $num_1;
if ($str_1 =~ /(\d+)/) {
    $num_1 = $1;
}
```

In Perl's patterns `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]` for ASCII strings.

Answer (score 1):

It could be:

```
$str="abc123defg";
$str =~ /[0-9]+/;
$num_1 = $&;
```

Your awk translates directly into:

```
$str="abc123defg";
$str =~ /[0-9]+/;
$num_1 = substr($str, $-[0], $+[0]-$-[0]);
```

Which could be written as:

```
use English;

$str="abc123defg";
$str =~ /[0-9]+/;
$num_1 = substr($str, $LAST_MATCH_START[0], $LAST_MATCH_END[0]-$LAST_MATCH_START[0]);
```